# How can I use SF Pro Rounded or a custom Font for Navigation titles in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to change the font for the Navigation View title to the system rounded one, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

To be clear, I can change the font fine on any Text View, List etc, but on the Navigation Title it seems to be impossible.

For reference the title ("Settings") in the app Carrot Weather achieves this: [image]

Any idea?

Thanks !!!

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57631230/14351818

Comment: I've seen it, but the [.font : UIFont(name: "Georgia-Bold", size: 20)!] doesn't take the system(.largetitle, design: .rounded) attribute, hence I can't get it to work with system font or even a custom font =/

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64304302/12299030?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`largeTitle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/textstyle/2921654-largetitle) to get the default navigation bar font, then apply rounding using [`withDesign(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontdescriptor/3151797-withdesign).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        var titleFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle) /// the default large title font
        titleFont = UIFont(
            descriptor:
                titleFont.fontDescriptor
                .withDesign(.rounded)? /// make rounded
                .withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold) /// make bold
                ??
                titleFont.fontDescriptor, /// return the normal title if customization failed
            size: titleFont.pointSize
        )
        
        /// set the rounded font
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font: titleFont]
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello World!")
                .navigationTitle("Dashboard") /// use this for iOS 14+
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Rounded navigation bar title]

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically update this font?  So that if a user changes an in app setting for the font they want to use as the 'theme', that we can then update the textAttributes?