# Change font size of NavigationTitle in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigation

I wanted to change the font size of the `navigationTitle` to `.footnote`
I tried to search but all the solutions i came up on internet were related to `navigationBarTitle`

Here is my Code:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            CoverImageView()
                .frame(height: 300)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .navigationTitle("Title")
//wanted to make "Title" appear as .footnote fontsize
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the appearance of the `UINavigationBar` also seems to affect the `navigationTitle`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .footnote)]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .footnote)]
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                CoverImageView()
                    .frame(height: 300)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Title")
        }
    }
}
```

(Code based on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57631230/15372665))

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this works temporarily but there are couple of concerns:
1. It seems like `UINavigationBar` belongs to UIKit and not swiftUI (Clarify me if I am wrong because I am new to this)
2. What if i want to change other properties (If you can attach some reference link where I can get more help)

Thnx

Comment: 1. You don't need to import UIKit for UINavigationBar (and UIFont) - it works just with SwiftUI. 
2. You can change all other properties associated with UINavigationBar.appearance() in the same manner. You can of course set your own custom fonts (e.g. `[.font : UIFont(name: "Georgia-Bold", size: 10)!]`. Here’s [some](https://youtu.be/mn5LlrF7Ih8?t=389) [examples](https://pacugindre.medium.com/customizing-swiftui-navigation-bar-8369d42b8805) I found.