# Swiftui page switch stuck when navigationbar changed in IOS17.2

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar

In Swiftui, when I jump from a page containing Navigationbar to a hidden page in Navigationbar, then swipe back, and then click on the jump button, the page will freeze and not respond.I used Iphone14 promax ,ios17.2.1,Tested normal on iOS 16
Here is my test code

```
struct TestVew : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack{
                NavigationLink {
                    SecondView()
                } label: {
                    Text("To SecondView")
                }

            }
            .navigationTitle("First page")
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("SecondView")
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}

extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }
}
```

I hope that when I click on NavigationLink again, it can jump to the page normally and return with normal gestures. Repeating the entire action should not get stuck

Comment: `NavigationView` is deprecated you shoud use `NavigationStack`. What is the code for your `extension UINavigationController` supposed to do. This is not SwiftUI code. Do you used that code somewhere? If so show what you do with it.

Comment: NavigationStack will be used starting from 16.0, and my project needs to support 15.0. In order to still achieve gesture right swipe back after hiding the Navigationbar ,I used extension UINavigationController,This is the result I found online, and it does work,I'll try NavigationStack to see if it has the same problem.Thank you

Comment: I tried using NavigationStack and it also has the same issue. My original intention was to achieve a navigationbar with rounded backgrounds, but it seems that the navigationbar cannot achieve the style I need. Therefore, I hid the navigationbar and used. ignoresSafeArea to customize the View. However, the above problem occurred. Do you know any way to set the navigationbar style for a specific page separately? This has been bothering me for several days. Thank you very much

Comment: I'm investigating your case and, it's a mistery why that happens. As for the NavigationBar style you can give a look at an answer I gave just earlier today where I create a custom Navigation bar:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77863134/swiftui-list-navigation-title-font-and-padding-update/77865664#77865664. In the mean time I'll look more into your real issue.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine that UIKit code is being called when any navigation occurs, or when swiping the finger to go back. I even tried not using it but the navigation gets stuck anyway. I'm trying with a cusotm swipe to pop gesture and the result is the same, you get stuck if you enter SecondView twice. This is really weird... SwiftUI never fails to surprise me everyday.

Comment: @MatBuompy The problem seems to only occur on IOS17, when the system navigation bar switches to the custom navigation bar and returns, it does not occur when switching between other navigation bars. To supplement the phenomenon: After jumping and sliding back, it seems that as long as a new navigation event is triggered, it will get stuck. Normal sliding will not have any impact. In addition, when it gets stuck, switch to the background and then reopen the app, and it seems to have new surprises

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be caused by using navigationTitle and navigationBarHidden(true) together. Commenting one of them makes the code run as it should. Why? That's anyone's guess. Now, I have solution for having the swipe gesture work and do any customisation (iOS 15+ compatible) you want to your header:

```
struct FullSwipeNavigationStack<Content: View>: View {
    
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    @ViewBuilder var content: Content
    @State private var customGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        gesture.name = UUID().uuidString
        gesture.isEnabled = true
        return gesture
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            content
                .background {
                    AttachGestureView(gesture: $customGesture)
                }
            
        }
        .environment(\.popGestureID, customGesture.name)
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .init(customGesture.name ?? "")), perform: { info in
            if let userInfo = info.userInfo, let status = userInfo["status"] as? Bool {
                customGesture.isEnabled = status
            }
        })
    }
}

/// Custom Environment key for passing Gesture ID to its subviews
fileprivate struct PopNotificationID: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: String?
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var popGestureID: String? {
        get {
            self[PopNotificationID.self]
        }
        set {
            self[PopNotificationID.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func enableFullSwipePop(_ isEnabled: Bool) -> some View {
        self.modifier(FullSwipeModifier(isEnabled: isEnabled))
    }
    
}

fileprivate struct FullSwipeModifier: ViewModifier {
    var isEnabled: Bool
    @Environment(\.popGestureID) private var gestureID
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onChange(of: isEnabled) { newValue  in
                guard let gestureID else {return}
                NotificationCenter.default.post(
                    name: .init(gestureID), object: nil,
                    userInfo: [
                        "status": newValue
                    ]
                )
            }
            .onDisappear {
                guard let gestureID else {return}
                NotificationCenter.default.post(
                    name: .init(gestureID), object: nil,
                    userInfo: [
                        "status": false
                    ]
                )
            }
    }
}

    struct AttachGestureView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        return UIView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.02) {
            // Look for parent controller
            if let parentViewController = uiView.parentViewController {
                if let navigationController = parentViewController.navigationController {
                    if let _ = navigationController.view.gestureRecognizers?.first(where: {
                        $0.name == gesture.name}) {
                        print("Already Attached")
                    } else {
                        navigationController.addFullSwipeGesture(gesture)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}

fileprivate extension UINavigationController {
    
    func addFullSwipeGesture(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let gestureSelector = interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.value(forKey: "targets") else {return}
        gesture.setValue(gestureSelector, forKey: "targets")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
    
}

fileprivate extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        sequence(first: self) {
            $0.next
        }.first(where: {$0 is UIViewController}) as? UIViewController
    }
}
```

I know it's a lot of code, but with this you can make any view have the swipe to go back gesture. You use it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        FullSwipeNavigationStack {
            TestVew()
        }
    }
}

struct TestView : View {
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            NavigationLink("To Second View") {
                SecondView()
            }
            //.navigationTitle("First page") // <-- Replace this with a custom Header
        }
    }
}
```

Also, as I said, if you want a custo navigation you can check my other answer here [Custom Navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77863134/swiftui-list-navigation-title-font-and-padding-update/77865664#77865664).
Let me know if that worked for you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your case can solve the problem of losing the sliding return gesture after customizing the navigation bar, and it is very suitable when all are custom navigation bars. However, if you jump from the system's navigation bar page to the custom navigation bar page and then return, it will still get stuck. I guess IOS17 may have caused some new problems, because your solution on IOS16 can indeed solve my problem

Comment: If my solution was of any help can you at least upvote it?

Comment: Sorry, this can help me understand how to handle UINavigationController in Swiftui, but it cannot solve the problem of getting stuck or help me understand why it gets stuck. If there are no more answers, I will adopt your suggestion

Comment: You getting stuck I think it's a SwiftUI bug and you can only find workarounds to it like my solution. And actually I asked for an upvote, not to mark it as correct. But it's ok, since you can't even upvote because your reputation is too low. You can only mark answers as correct so far.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. I am a beginner and my reputation is not good enough, but I still appreciate your help