# NavigationBarHidden with swipe back

Tags: swiftui

To enable swipe back in a view with the navigation bar hidden, we set the navigationController's interactivePopGestureRecognizer delegate. When returning to the main screen by swiping back and then entering detailView again, the screen freezes. This phenomenon occurs only in iOS 17. It works normally in iOS16. I am curious as to why this phenomenon occurs in iOS 17 and how to resolve it.

this is the sample code that we used.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                Text("Go to Detail")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Main")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail View")
            .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
    }
}

extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }
}
```

I tried to use viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad. But results were same.

Comment: You may have to use `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. 

Comment: Doesn't the NavigationStack provide the swipe back feature. Normally there is no extra work to do.

Comment: I answered a similar question where I provided a cusom implementation of the swipe to pop gesture here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77865035/swiftui-page-switch-stuck-when-navigationbar-changed-in-ios17-2/77866820#77866820. Let me know if this works.