Use the SF Rounded font for all text by default in SwiftUI
I keep manually specifying design: .rounded:
.font(.system(.title2, design: .rounded, weight: .semibold))

How do I use Apple's rounded font for all text by default?

You only need to put this .font(...) modifier at the very root of your app, and it should propagate automatically down the view hierarchy.

I tried that and it says "Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'rounded'". Sorry if this is a dumb question, I am very new to SwiftUI and I'm finding the docs very unhelpful.

If I understand correctly, you should use the fontDesign modifier. You can put this at the very root of your view hierarchy:
@main
struct FooApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().fontDesign(.rounded)
        }
    }
}

Note that this will override the font design you set with the .font modifier. Suppose you have
Text("Hello World")
    .font(.system(.body, design: .serif))

this will not have a serif font due to .fontDesign(.rounded). If this is undesirable for some views, apply .fontDesign(nil) to those views.

Thanks, that seems to work, although for some reason it has not changed the font of navigationTitle.

@OllieWilliams Navigation titles are notoriously not customisable in SwiftUI. You can do that in UIKit though. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/56590899/5133585

@OllieWilliams Actually this post is more relevant. Just change .serif in that post to .rounded. Do note that in modern versions you should create a UINavigationBarAppearance object instead of setting UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes, like in this answer.

Works like a charm, thank you!

UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes does seem to work, why do you say it shouldn't be used? It doesn't seem to be deprecated.

@OllieWilliams it’s not deprecated, but it’s “legacy”. I remember running into some problems using them (can’t remember what exactly though).

I know that Apple aren't going to deprecate UIKit anytime soon and that its ok to mix SwiftUI and UIKit, but I am trying to stick to SwiftUI as much as possible. I only just noticed that most of this seems to be using UIKit. I wonder if there is a SwiftUI equivalent? I read this article and it doesn't mention it so maybe it isn't possible in SwiftUI? https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/customizing-the-navigation-bar-appearance

@OllieWilliams It's not possible at the moment. Perhaps we get it in the future :)
